# Laravel on server with ip

Tags: laravel

I have to install a laravel application on a customer server. Local with homestead and on my test server, the application runs without any problems.
The customer url is only a ip.
On the customer server, there is 403 on login. `57.6.7.37/login`.
When i put on top in the index.php the following code, the browser shows the text "test" correctly:

```
<?php

echo "Test";
exit;
//The rest of the index.php code
```

It isn't possible to run a laravel application only with an ip address?
Or does someone have an idea where i have to search? Thanks

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure it's just a case of making sure the ip resolves to  the public folder of your app and not the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

in side your **config/app.php** set this :

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://57.6.7.37'),
```

in your **.env** file :

```
APP_URL=http://57.6.7.37
```